# Show that there is no $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

It’s been years since I took linear algebra and my niece just asked me for help with this problem. Can anyone help please? Thank you!

Comment: Ask your niece to explain the concepts to you. It may bring up some of your old memories of linear algebra that help. Otherwise, the question here will just be put on hold until you can provide more details about what you have tried when attempting a solution (even if it is your niece's homework problem, you're the one here asking).

Comment: A start for you niece would be to try a arbitrary matrix [a,b] [c,d] and multiply it with itself and then equate it with $A$ and try to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Because it could simplify the argument, do you require that $B$ would have integer entries? Rational entries? Real entries?

Answer (score 11):

The following is under the assumption that you *actually meant* that there is **no real matrix** $\;B\;$ such that...

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}=B^2\implies \det A=\det B^2=(\det B)^2$$

and now check what the determinant of $\;A\;$ is...